# RegEx (or RegEx-like) validation rules?

Tags: microsoft-access, microsoft-access-2002

I've built my own (crude) version control system for Access and I'm looking to validate the version number in my update log table.

The version number should match the regular expression `[0-9]+\.[0-9]+[a-z]?` but I can't figure out how to implement this as a validation rule for the field. Can this actually be done, if so, how?

*Note: I'm fairly fluent with VBA so VBA-based solutions are fine*

Comment: There is a regex addin for VBA.  It can do what you want.

Comment: @wbeard52 I can use regex within VBA just fine by using the VBScript regex object, but I'd like data validation at the table level that can use regex patterns. If this unspecified addin you mention can do that then please provide more details and post it as an answer.